# CursorLoader android

Tags: java, android

I have recently discovered the CursorLoader class from Udacity course but when I headed towards the google doc I realized that it has been deprecated. So now I want to know what are it's alternative also I haven't understand the role of this class so can anyone explain this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

LiveData and ViewModel replace CursorLoaders

actually, ViewModel handles survival across config change, and LiveData replaces the Loader data loaded callbacks, but they don't for example replace the cursor-based loading mechanism that allows loading large data sets in a lazy manner.

The actual replacement for that will be the new DataSource API in the Paging library which is currently alpha4. Then, CursorLoader will be replaced by LivePagedListBuilder, and just PagedList in general, with RecyclerView integration through PagedListAdapter.

Comment: Can you send me a page illustrating on how this is done. Since I'm new to this and am unable to understand like this.

Comment: Also I saw that this class is not deprecated in androidX library what does that mean? Is this class still valid and has just been transferred to a new library or just that it is kept their so that people can still use it if they want to?